# Is there a way to set a machine-level "cookie?"

Tags: http, cookies

Is there any standard way of creating and reading a machine-level (not user-specific) cookie-like persistent setting? Thus, if the value is set while user X is browsing, then if user X logs off the machine and user Y logs in and goes to the same site, the value set during user X's session can be read?

This is for an internal application. I have done something like this using ActiveX controls in IE, but we do not want to have a dependency on IE but rather be able to support Chrome and other browsers. It is OK if each browser has their own implementation; they do not have to be able to share the value across browsers.

Even a read-only solution could work, as an admin user could do the creation phase out of band, as long as the setting could be read by all users' sessions and sent with an HTTP request.

Comment: Why do you not store that value on your server and serve it with your response to desired set of users?

Comment: @KresoJurisic: The value would differ *per machine*, not per user. User X could / should send a *different* value on a different machine. Like REMOTE_ADDR, only custom data.

Comment: @RDardelet: Not a duplicate at all. This question concerns user-level vs. machine-level storage, not persistent vs. non-persistent cookies.

Comment: Good point, my bad